# Strategy for moving javascript to the bottom in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, performance, codeigniter

On my site I have one global Javascript file which includes jQuery and code for the drop down menu among other things. Many pages also have custom Javascript for minor page-specific interactions, tables etc.

My current set up on each view is a `header.php` file, basically covering everything from the doctype through to start of the content, the view file for the specific page, and a `footer.php` closing out the page.

Currently `global.js` is linked from the `<head>`. For performance we should put JS at the very bottom of the page, but I can't figure out a good way to do this. I could add the full script line for `global.js` with the custom script block, but that means I must add it on every page, even when there is no other Javascript. Any better way to move the JS right to the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the custom JS in a regular variable or [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (php 5.3.0+), and then echo the variable along with script tags in the footer if it exists. Nowdoc might be preferable because you can use both double quotes and single quotes in your JS **and** PHP won't parse/escape the text.

someview.php:

```
<?php 
$custom_js = "
alert('custom js ran');
";
?>

<?php 
$custom_js = <<<'CUSTOM_JS'
alert("custom js ran (i'm in a nowdoc!)");
CUSTOM_JS;
?>
```

footer.php:

```
<?php if(isset($custom_js)) { ?>
    <script><?php echo $custom_js; ?></script>
<?php } ?>
```

**Edit 2:** 
If you don't want to have the javascript in a string, you could have the javascript in a seperate file and then use PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to load it into the `$custom_js` variable as a string.

**Edit:**
This is just an aside, but you might look into using the Carabiner library for loading JS and CSS. It's an excellent library. It might not necessarily help with your current problem, but if your global.js is quite large, you could split it up and use Carabiner to compress/concatenate on load. I currently use it to select which JS and CSS gets loaded for logged in and logged out users on my current CI project.

- [Carabiner on Github](https://github.com/mikedfunk/carabiner/)
- [Carabiner on Sparks](http://getsparks.org/packages/carabiner/versions/HEAD/show)
- [Carabiner documentation](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Carabiner)

Comment: Thanks. Not a bad answer, but it does mean the Javascript has to be inside a PHP string which is a little annoying.

Comment: why? it doesnt matter. when the script is run, the html will appear as pure text. I do this exact answer with excellent results

Comment: This to me seems the fastest and most sensible option.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this, but this is probably the simplest one. You could have a switch statement in footer.php and switch based on the URL, but then you have to have every custom snippet of JS in the footer.php and you'll have to update footer.php every time you make a new view that requires a new custom snippet.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I'm aware of that; the problem is outputting JS via PHP strings is cumbersome, breaks syntax highlighting and has many pitfalls with quotes etc.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks, I completely forgot about that syntax. Is there any other difference between heredoc and nowdoc, apart from using variables in heredoc? Not sure I have 5.3 on my server.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I missed something - but why cant you just load another view, which only contains the js code?

Your template:

```
$this->load->view("header.php");
$this->load->view("content.php", $data);
$this->load->view("footer.php", $load_js);
```

Then inside footer.php:

```
   // start of footer stuff here
   $this->load->view($load_js);
</body>
</html>
```

Then inside page1.php:

```
<script>
   // Your scripts here
</script>
```

**OR:**

Your template:

```
$this->load->view("header.php");
$this->load->view("content.php", $data);
```

Then inside each "content.php" file:

```
 // Content goes here
$data['load_js'] = "page1.php";
$this->load->view("footer.php", $data);
```

Then inside single "footer.php" file:

```
   // start of footer stuff here
   $this->load->view($load_js);
</body>
</html>
```

Then inside page1.php:

```
<script>
   // Your scripts here
</script>
```

The second method is probably more what you want. It does mean you need to call the footer in each content file - but it is literally one line - so your not really repeating yourself - but it gives you complete control inside the content file to specifically any js files to load.

You can expand this an make the $load_js variable an array of js files to load.

Comment: The problem here is that I have different custom Javascript for most pages. I need some way of specifying that in `content.php` but outputting it at the bottom of the page, which is in `footer.php`.

Comment: Given you are trying to load the JS at the bottom of the page for "performance" - then you should really be compressing and minimizing ALL your JS into ONE file, and just load that in the footer. Loading the JS individually for each page means you are sending a significant amount of extra information for EACH page request with NO caching. This is terrible for performance.

Comment: anyway I've modified my answer, so you can just specify which JS file to load when you call the template. But personally I think you need to just reconsider and put it all into 1-2 files.

Comment: OK thanks for the updates. Maybe I didn't explain it well enough in the question but separate JS is required because there is a set chunk of JS that appears on every page (i.e. the jQuery library) then some small jQuery snippets on different pages. The "big chunk" is one file that is cached fine. It would be silly to have the same 80KB of Javascript in a uniquely-named file on every page.

Comment: ok - makes more sense - but you could still combine all those "snippets" into one js file for optimal performance. Either way my solution above will work - I do something similar

Answer (score 1):

I use a set of layouts, which are views that provide the basic structure of the site. Every controller calls a layout and passes into it the content specific for that controller method.

For example, say you have a single layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $page->title ?></title>
    <?php if (count($page->css)): ?>
       <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($page->css); $i++): ?>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $page->css[$i] ?>"/>
       <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php $this->load->view('header.php'); ?>

    <?php $this->load->view($content); ?>        

    <?php $this->load->view('footer.php'); ?>

    <?php if (count($page->js)): ?>
      <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($page->js); $i++): ?>
        <script src="<?php echo $page->js[$i] ?>"></script>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Each page passes in a `$page` object that contains an array of css and js files. For files that are global, like global.js, you can just hardcode that in at the bottom (same with global CSS at the top). Or, you can set a parent controller that all controllers inherit from. This way you can set up the `$page` object with default settings (including adding global.js). Then, each controller/method can remove global.js if it's not needed.

Each page also passes in a `$content` variable with the location of the main view for the page.

You can extend this even further by having multiple layouts and moving some of the HTML into the layout (e.g. 1 column, 2 column, 3 column layouts). In those cases, you may pass in multiple view locations for each column, etc. It's really up to you.

Of course, to keep all JS at the bottom you'd need to move all your page-specific custom JS into JS files. That's actually the best way to go, considering external JS can be cached.

Comment: The page-specific JS isn't particularly large (just a few lines in some cases) so creating an extra JS file for each page would be *more* overhead. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: If the page-specific JS is just a few lines, then you can keep it in your content view. The above would still save you from having to add global.js to every page (and header/footer.php)

Comment: @minboost if you could just add a sample code of how a method in the controller would set up the data and load this 'template', it will seal the deal.

Comment: @minboost In the off chance that the header.php wants to reference data passed from the controller, will it automagically have access to it or will we have to pass it again.  I just place the entire content of header.php and footer.php in this file and call it template.php

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper function; and load a view where you include that `global.js` script. Anytime you need global.js to be located at the bottom of the page, just call that helper function.

Comment: The `global.js` needs to be included on *every* page, so this answer sin't really ideal.

Comment: Included inside Controller, wherever you want to add. This a true approach. Just read the question again!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a template library.

I use this one by [Williams Concepts](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html).
It allows you to add JS (and CSS for that matter) for individual class/method calls.
For example:

```
class foo exends Controller {
    public function bar() {
        $this->template->add_js('js/jquery.js');
        $this->template->add_js('alert("Hello!");', 'embed');

        $data = $this->some_model->get_data();
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'user/profile', $data;

        $this->template->render();
    }
}
```

Using this you can either add the JS as and when required, or add it into the template for the site.
In your case, I would either add the global.js in the footer of the template or define a region in the footer of the template when you can add any JS required.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller / add function**

```
public function add()
    {
        $data['page_title'] = 'Test | Add Details';
        $data['js'] = array('details','details2');

        $this->load->view('template/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('details/add');
        $this->load->view('template/footer',$data);
    }
```

in your footer template load all the common scripts that are needed, like jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js and so on. later add the below code

**footer**

```
 <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>   

    <?php 
    if(isset($js) && count($js) > 0)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($js);$i++)
        {

    ?>
        <script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/js/custom/<?= $js[$i] ?>.js"></script>
    <?php
        }
    } 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

pass all the js files to be loaded in the array.

Comment: This is fine if you have a big chunk of JS to add to a page, but in my original case I wanted very small snippets (2-4 lines). Linking separate scripts for each of those is bad for performance.

Comment: in that case you can use script tags in view. make sure jQuery file is loaded before your script is called or else it will give $. undefined

Answer (score -1):

If you have a footer.php file that's included on everypage, why can't you just put your js code in that file?

Comment: Because as I said, "Many pages also have custom Javascript for minor page-specific interactions"

Comment: What does that matter? If you have a global footer, you can add your global js in there.

Comment: Because then the page-specific Javascript comes before the global JS. The 'global' stuff contains jQuery which needs to be before any code that uses jQuery.

Comment: Oh i get your problem now. You have page specific js in the page itself. You could just move all of your js to one global js file rather than have individual pieces on each page.

Comment: Someone else mentioned that above... I don't see how that is possible because the JS is specific to that page. Trying to run it on other pages would cause errors. Although I think stuff like `$('#special_element').dosomething()` doesn't give an error in jQuery, but it would still be searching for 20 things that don't exist, *on every page load*.

Comment: You can check if the element exists before performing an action on it. See http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/check-if-an-element-exists-using-jquery/ for example.